# How to make count down not reset when you refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shopify

I got this count down for my shopify website and it works just fine, except for when you refresh the page. When you do that the thing just resets itself. Can anyone please help me to fix this? Thank you in advance!

This is the code:

````
<style>#progress_bar{margin-top:15px}.progressbar.progressbar{background:#ffe8e8;border:0px solid whitesmoke;height:11px}.progressbar.progressbar div{background:#d95350;height:11px}{border-radius:16px}.progressbar.progressbar.active div{-webkit-animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes;animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes}.progress-striped.progressbar.progressbar div{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));background-size:40px 40px}.items-count{margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px}.count{color:#a94442;padding:1px}.items-count p{padding-bottom:5px;margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:700;text-align:center;font-family:"DIN Next",Arial,sans-serif}.progressbar{position:relative;display:block;background-color:#ca0000;border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:15px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)}.progressbar > div{background-color:#ca0000;width:0;margin-bottom:0;height:15px}.progressbar > div.less-than-ten{background-color:#ca0000 !important}#clock-ticker{display:block;margin-bottom:15px}#clock-ticker .block{position:relative;color:#000;font-weight:bold;float:left;text-align:center;width:25%}#clock-ticker .block .flip-top{width:88px;height:39px;line-height:40px;font-size:40px;text-align:center}#clock-ticker .block .label,span.flip-top{color:#000;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:14px;text-transform:uppercase;width:88px;line-height:25px;font-family:"Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif}</style><style>.progressbar div{border-radius:20px}</style><style>#progress_bar div{border-radius:20px}</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);}

// Settings are here
var total_items = 50;
var d = new Date();
var min_items_left = 8;
var max_items_left = 12;
var remaining_items = randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left, max_items_left);
var min_of_remaining_items = 3;
var decrease_after = 1.7; 
var decrease_after_first_item = 0.17; 

// Davy Jones' Locker
(function($){$.fn.progressbar=function(){var a="<p>Only <span class='count'>"+remaining_items+"</span> items remaining</p>"+"<div class='progressbar'><div style='width:100%'></div></div>";this.addClass('items-count');this.html(a+this.html());updateMeter(this);var b=this;setTimeout(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}$('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');$('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){$('.count').css('background-color','#fff');$('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after_first_item);setInterval(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}$('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');$('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){$('.count').css('background-color','#fff');$('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after)};function updateMeter(a){var b=100*remaining_items/total_items;if(remaining_items<10){a.find('.progressbar div:first').addClass('less-than-ten')}a.find('.progressbar').addClass('active progress-striped');setTimeout(function(){myanimate(a.find('.progressbar div:first'),b);a.find('.progressbar').removeClass('active progress-striped')},1000)}}(jQuery));function myanimate(a,b){var c=0;var d=parseInt(a.closest('.progressbar').css('width'));var e=Math.floor(100*parseInt(a.css('width'))/d);if(e>b){c=e}function frame(){if(e>b){c--}else{c++}a.css('width',c+'%');if(c==b||c<=0||c>=100)clearInterval(f)}var f=setInterval(frame,40)} jQuery.noConflict()(function($){$(document).ready(function(){$("#progress_bar").progressbar();var tag="ctdn-12-12".match(/\d+/g);var hour=14;var theDaysBox=$("#numdays");var theHoursBox=$("#numhours");var theMinsBox=$("#nummins");var theSecsBox=$("#numsecs");var d=new Date();var n=d.getDay();var date=1;var gg=0;var hh=0;var ii=0;var nsec=0-d.getSeconds();if(nsec<0){nsec=60-d.getSeconds();gg=1}var nmin=0-d.getMinutes()-gg;if(nmin<0){nmin=60-d.getMinutes()-gg;hh=1}var nhrs=14-d.getHours()-hh;if(nhrs<0){nhrs=38-d.getHours()-hh;ii=1}var ndat=date-1;if(ndat<0){var mmon=d.getMonth();ndat=30+date-d.getDate()-ii}theSecsBox.html(nsec);theMinsBox.html(nmin);theHoursBox.html(nhrs);theDaysBox.html(ndat);var refreshId=setInterval(function(){var e=theSecsBox.text();var a=theMinsBox.text();var c=theHoursBox.text();var b=theDaysBox.text();if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0&&b==0){}else{if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0){theDaysBox.html(b-1);theHoursBox.html("23");theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0&&a==0){theHoursBox.html(c-1);theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0){theMinsBox.html(a-1);theSecsBox.html("59")}else{theSecsBox.html(e-1)}}}}},1000);});});</script>```
````

Comment: Check how setItem is definied. You are setting value for "key". You should set the value you are trying to store. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: please clean up the code example so we can have a non-scrolling experience.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know pretty much anything about coding. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `SessionStorage`. Store the count for day, hour, minute and second in SessionStorage using web storage API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

When the page reloads read the values set in sessionStorage, if found. If not use the usual values extracted from Date().

You can run the stack snippet shown below to view normal operation. Stack snippet doesn't allow reading 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window' as the document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

So i have commented the code that i have inserted and also set if conditions to be changed later when you run the code in real environment. In the snippet below it's:
`if (false && sessionStorage)`
you can run this code in your browser by changing those `if` conditions to:
`if (sessionStorage)`
You will see the counter value is retained on page refresh.

```js
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

// Settings are here
var total_items = 50;
var d = new Date();
var min_items_left = 8;
var max_items_left = 12;

// declare storage keys first here, it's easy to manage that way.
const StorageKeys = {
  counterItems: 'my-counter-items',
  counter: 'my-counter'
};

/** Start: Insert this code to read session Storage for counter Items **/
// here you can pull the sessionStored value 
let counterItems = null;
// NOTE: remove false from condition check before running in real env
if (false && sessionStorage) {
 counterItems = sessionStorage.getItem(StorageKeys.counterItems);
}
/** End: Insert this code to read session Storage for counter Items **/

// use stored items count if present
var remaining_items = counterItems ? Number(counterItems) : randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left, max_items_left);

var min_of_remaining_items = 3;
var decrease_after = 1.7;
var decrease_after_first_item = 0.17;

// Davy Jones' Locker
(function($) {
  $.fn.progressbar = function() {
    var a = "<p>Only <span class='count'>" + remaining_items + "</span> items remaining</p>" + "<div class='progressbar'><div style='width:100%'></div></div>";
    this.addClass('items-count');
    this.html(a + this.html());
    updateMeter(this);
    var b = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      remaining_items--;
      if (remaining_items < min_of_remaining_items) {
        remaining_items = randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left, max_items_left)
      }
      $('.count').css('background-color', '#CE0201');
      $('.count').css('color', '#fff');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.count').css('background-color', '#fff');
        $('.count').css('color', '#CE0201')
      }, 1000 * 60 * 0.03);
      b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);
      updateMeter(b)
    }, 1000 * 60 * decrease_after_first_item);
    setInterval(function() {
      remaining_items--;
      if (remaining_items < min_of_remaining_items) {
        remaining_items = randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left, max_items_left)
      }
      $('.count').css('background-color', '#CE0201');
      $('.count').css('color', '#fff');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.count').css('background-color', '#fff');
        $('.count').css('color', '#CE0201')
      }, 1000 * 60 * 0.03);
      b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);
      updateMeter(b)
    }, 1000 * 60 * decrease_after)
  };

  function updateMeter(a) {
    /** Start: Insert this code to set session Storage for counter Items **/
    // now save the counter items values in sessionStorage
    // NOTE: remove false from condition check before running in real env
    if(false && sessionStorage) {
      sessionStorage.setItem(StorageKeys.counterItems, remaining_items);
    }
    /** End: Insert this code to set session Storage for counter Items **/
    
    var b = 100 * remaining_items / total_items;
    if (remaining_items < 10) {
      a.find('.progressbar div:first').addClass('less-than-ten')
    }
    a.find('.progressbar').addClass('active progress-striped');
    setTimeout(function() {
      myanimate(a.find('.progressbar div:first'), b);
      a.find('.progressbar').removeClass('active progress-striped')
    }, 1000)
  }
}(jQuery));

function myanimate(a, b) {
  var c = 0;
  var d = parseInt(a.closest('.progressbar').css('width'));
  var e = Math.floor(100 * parseInt(a.css('width')) / d);
  if (e > b) {
    c = e
  }

  function frame() {
    if (e > b) {
      c--
    } else {
      c++
    }
    a.css('width', c + '%');
    if (c == b || c <= 0 || c >= 100) clearInterval(f)
  }
  var f = setInterval(frame, 40)
}

jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progress_bar").progressbar();
    var tag = "ctdn-12-12".match(/\d+/g);
    var hour = 14;
    var theDaysBox = $("#numdays");
    var theHoursBox = $("#numhours");
    var theMinsBox = $("#nummins");
    var theSecsBox = $("#numsecs");
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var date = 1;
    var gg = 0;
    var hh = 0;
    var ii = 0;
    var nsec = 0 - d.getSeconds();
    if (nsec < 0) {
      nsec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
      gg = 1
    }
    var nmin = 0 - d.getMinutes() - gg;
    if (nmin < 0) {
      nmin = 60 - d.getMinutes() - gg;
      hh = 1
    }
    var nhrs = 14 - d.getHours() - hh;
    if (nhrs < 0) {
      nhrs = 38 - d.getHours() - hh;
      ii = 1
    }
    var ndat = date - 1;
    if (ndat < 0) {
      var mmon = d.getMonth();
      ndat = 30 + date - d.getDate() - ii
    }
    
    /** Start: Insert this code to read session Storage **/
    // here read from Session Storage; you can use any
    // keyname to store the values
    let counterData = null;
    // NOTE: remove false from condition check before running in real env
    if(false && sessionStorage) {
      counterData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(StorageKeys.counter));
    }
    /** End: Insert this code to read session Storage **/
   
    // use the stored valued value if present
    theSecsBox.html(counterData ? counterData.nsec : nsec);
    theMinsBox.html(counterData ? counterData.nmin : nmin);
    theHoursBox.html(counterData ? counterData.nhrs : nhrs);
    theDaysBox.html(counterData ? counterData.ndat : ndat);
    
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      var e = theSecsBox.text();
      var a = theMinsBox.text();
      var c = theHoursBox.text();
      var b = theDaysBox.text();
      
      /** Start: Insert this code to set session Storage **/
      // now save the counter values in sessionStorage
      // NOTE: remove false from condition check before running in real env
      if(false && sessionStorage) {
        const currentValues = { nsec: e, nmin: a, nhrs: c, ndat: b };
        sessionStorage.setItem(StorageKeys.counter, JSON.stringify(currentValues));
      }
      /** End: Insert this code to set session Storage **/
            
      if (e == 0 && a == 0 && c == 0 && b == 0) {} else {
        if (e == 0 && a == 0 && c == 0) {
          theDaysBox.html(b - 1);
          theHoursBox.html("23");
          theMinsBox.html("59");
          theSecsBox.html("59")
        } else {
          if (e == 0 && a == 0) {
            theHoursBox.html(c - 1);
            theMinsBox.html("59");
            theSecsBox.html("59")
          } else {
            if (e == 0) {
              theMinsBox.html(a - 1);
              theSecsBox.html("59")
            } else {
              theSecsBox.html(e - 1)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#progress_bar {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.progressbar.progressbar {
  background: #ffe8e8;
  border: 0px solid whitesmoke;
  height: 11px;
}

.progressbar.progressbar div {
  background: #d95350;
  height: 11px;
}

  {
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.progressbar.progressbar.active div {
  -webkit-animation: 2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes;
  animation: 2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes;
}

.progress-striped.progressbar.progressbar div {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}

.items-count {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.count {
  color: #a94442;
  padding: 1px;
}

.items-count p {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "DIN Next", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.progressbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ca0000;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.progressbar > div {
  background-color: #ca0000;
  width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 15px;
}

.progressbar > div.less-than-ten {
  background-color: #ca0000 !important;
}

#clock-ticker {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#clock-ticker .block {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

#clock-ticker .block .flip-top {
  width: 88px;
  height: 39px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#clock-ticker .block .label, span.flip-top {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 88px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.progressbar div {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#progress_bar div {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress_bar"></div>
<span id="numdays"></span> days
<span id="numhours"></span> Hours
<span id="nummins"></span> Minutes
<span id="numsecs"></span> Seconds
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help! The timer now works flawlessly indeed, but unfortunately the 'Only 7 items remaining' part still resets with every refresh. Could you please help me out with that as well? Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Sure :) 
I have updated the code to store items count in sessionStorage as well. Also refactored how we are using storageKey by declaring them upfront, that makes it easier to maintain. The new code injected in also commented with proper directions for usage.

Comment: Your sir... Are a legend! Thank you so much, it works flawlessly now!

Answer (score 0):

I would create something like:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, html, bod, I, SessionCounter; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body;
I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
SessionCounter = function(init = 0, inc = 1, dec = 1){
  if(sessionStorage.count === undefined){
    sessionStorage.count = init;
  }
  this.count = +sessionStorage.count;
  this.inc = (by = inc)=>{
    this.count += by; sessionStorage.count = this.count;
    return this.count;
  }
  this.dec = (by = dec)=>{
    this.count -= by; sessionStorage.count = this.count;
    return this.count;
  }
}
// you can put the following on another page using a load Event - besides the end load
const dec = I('dec'), test = I('test'), inc = I('inc');
sc = new SessionCounter;
test.textContent = sc.count;
dec.onclick = ()=>{
  if(sc.count > 0)test.textContent = sc.dec();
}
inc.onclick = ()=>{
  test.textContent = sc.inc();
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc;
}
.main{
  padding:10px;
}
#inc,#dec{
  width:20px;
}
#test{
  display:inline-block; width:70px; background:#fff; text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div>
      <input id='dec' type='button' value='-' />
      <div id='test'></div>
      <input id='inc' type='button' value='+' />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, time and effort! I truly appreciate it, but unfortunately I really don't know what to do with the code you gave me :(

Comment: `<script src='js/external.js'></script>` is the script tag in HTML. It refers to the JavaScript page, which is its own separate page. You should keep your JavaScript separate from your HTML, putting your script tags in your `<head>`. Run all of your code on subsequent pages in `addEventListener('load', ()=>{ /* in here */})`. Also you should learn Object Oriented design. 'new` creates a `new` instance of an Object. Until then the constructor is just a function. `this` refers to the `new` instance itself, accept in Arrow functions where it scopes up a level and stays. In time... in time.

Comment: Thank you so much !